# Add AAAA record in Google Cloud DNS

Tags: ssl, dns, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-dns

Hei guys so I got an issue on my website, it can't be accessed because the SSL certificate can't be renew and then when I do script for renew it give some error because the AAAA record. So I need to add AAAA record on my google cloud dns

> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>      entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
>      contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
>      your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
>      firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
>      client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
>      that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.

My question is how to know ipv6 in my compute engine ? because I only knew my ipv4, please help me guys. thank you

[image]

Comment: That error message does NOT mean you need to configure IPv6 (AAAA). Just make sure your A record is correct. The error message means that they cannot reach your domain. Unless you know how to setup and manage IPv6, don't enable it at this time.

Comment: hmm okay I don't know why they can't reach my domain

Comment: There are tools on the Internet for this: https://dnschecker.org/

Comment: As mentioned by John Hanley, this seems not to be related to IPv6, but out of curiosity, you need to use a [IPv6 termination in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ipv6) to be able to match to a AAAA record in Cloud DNS and it will not work natively with Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to App Engine and Settings and you will see something like attached. This is where you find the AAAA records. You can use app engine or computer engine or kubernetes engine but custom domain settings remain in App Engine settings.As attached
[image: Google Cloud Custom Domain Settings]